# Cannot locate 173 GB backups on hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, photos.app, storage

About my Mac Storage states that I have used 173 GB of my hard drive in backups.

Where are these?  My iPhoto library disappeared, and I have been unable to restore through Time Machine because it says I don't have enough space. How can I free the storage or find the backups to restore the iPhoto library.

<sup>OS X 10.9.5</sup>

Comment: Did you check the Trash?

Answer (score 1):

Open the **Terminal.app** and type `sudo du -k | awk '$1 > 500000' | sort -nr`, this command will search for all Directories bigger than 500MB and sort them by size. So you should find the Location to your Backups.